# Select data that is a month or less old

Tags: java, android, azure

I am using azure mobile service as a storage platform for an android app I am developing. How can I select data from a table that is a month or less old? This is the query in which I want to add that feature to:

```
final MobileServiceList<Crime> assaultNum = mToDoTable.where().field("county").eq(countyString).execute().get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The underlying data storage for Mobile Services is SQL Server, so if this is a core thing of your application, I would consider writing a view that gives you all data for upto a month back (either by timestamp or by a date field if you have one in the same table) and then perform the exact same query that you have there upon that view.

Comment: Where could I program a view though?

Comment: Check this thread for how to create a view in Mobile Services: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/639ada5b-1129-405a-b536-4c6163315aee/create-a-view-for-azure-mobile-services?forum=azuremobile

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to retrieve data based on the month in the date column:

```
 final MobileServiceList<Crime> assaultNum = mToDoTable.where().field("county").eq("Kildare South")
                            .and().month("date").eq(03).execute().get();
```

In english, this query selects rows where the county column is equal to Kildare South and the month in the date column is equal to march(03).